# Word choice: complement of 'Budgeted', but not 'Filled'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am trying to figure out a good word to use as a complement to *budgeted*. I've used *filled* before, and I would like to avoid using it again if possible.

**Context:** I am making a simple over/under budget table, with columns labeled *budgeted* and *"x"*.

Comment: I think you may need to explain what "budgeted" and "filled" actually **mean** in this context. *Fill* is AmE for "fulfil an order", but I can't relate it to *budgeted*.

Comment: What about *spent*?  E.g., The amount allocated/budgeted has already been spent.

Comment: Unless by *filled* you mean, the money has been budgeted but we have no idea where we're going to get it, in which case *funded* might be apropos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a line item budget report (in U.S. business and government usage, at least), the column indicating forecasted expenditures will typically be labeled *Budget* or *Budgeted* whereas the column indicating the actual expenditures will be labeled *Actual*.

The “Budget vs. Actual” report, i.e. the [budget variance report](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/budget-variance-analysis-60250.html), is [a basic report](http://wiki.fool.com/How_to_Calculate_Change_in_Budget_Vs._Actual) that can be [calculated on a spreadsheet](http://www.cimaglobal.com/Thought-leadership/Newsletters/Insight-e-magazine/Insight-2012/Insight-January-2012/Spreadsheet-skills-Modelling-Actual-versus-Budget/) or generated by any [accounting software](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/pages/inproducthelp/core/qb2k12/contentpackage/core/budget/..%5C..%5CCore/Reports_Description_Other/rpt_bud_pl_vs_actual.html).